# Error in tuneRF in R in if (n == 0) stop("data (x) has 0 rows") : argument is of length zero

Tags: r, random-forest, ctree

I would like to optimize the values of hyperparameters of `ctree()` (`randomforest`).
I use the function `tuneRF`. I get the following error:

```
Error in if (n == 0) stop("data (x) has 0 rows") : 
  argument is of length zero
```

Here is my code:

```
library(party)
library(randomForest)
library(mlbench)
dat1 <- fread('https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/abalone/abalone.data',stringsAsFactors=T)

## split data to train and test
set.seed(123)
dat1 <- subset(dat1, !is.na(V1))
smp_size =92
train_ind <- sample(seq_len(nrow(dat1)), size = smp_size)
train <- dat1[train_ind, ]
test <- dat1[-train_ind, ]

ct <- ctree(V1 ~ ., data = train)
```

And here is my trial for finding the `mtry`

```
bestmtry <- tuneRF(train$V1,  train[V2:V9], stepFactor=1.5, improve=1e-5, ntree=500)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a couple of issues,

```
bestmtry <- tuneRF(train[, V2:V9], train$V1, stepFactor = 1.5, improve = 1e-5, ntree = 500)
```

works.

Comment: Thanks @JuliusVainora! Does it mean that mtry = 6 is the optimal value?

Comment: To answer that, what's `smp_size`? It's not defined in your example.

Comment: Please elaborate what you mean in smp_size. I would like to increase the accuracy of ctree model using all the hyperparameters I can...

Comment: I mean that your example is not reproducible because `smp_size`, which is present in your code, isn't defined. For this reason, I cannot run `tuneRF` and answer your question about `mtry`.

Comment: smp_size =92 but it can be changed.

Comment: Practically, you can omit smp_size

Comment: When I run your code with `smp_size <- 92`, then only 2, 3, and 4 as values of `mtry` are considered, of which 3 is the best.

Comment: This is the results I get: mtry = 2  OOB error = 58.7% 
Searching left ...
Searching right ...
mtry = 3  OOB error = 57.61% 
0.01851852 1e-05 
mtry = 4  OOB error = 55.43% 
0.03773585 1e-05 
mtry = 6  OOB error = 55.43% 
0 1e-05 
Does it mean mtry =6 is the optimal ?

Comment: The lowest OOB error means the optimal choice. It looks like 4 and 6 both give the same 55.43%. In any case, that's not what your original question is about.

Comment: Thanks a lot again. Are there additional parameters I can optimize/tune by using some other functions?